# PythonでCoco Styleのjsonファイルを作りたい

Tags: python, json, annotations

PythonでCoco Styleのjsonファイルを作りたいです。

プログラミング初心者です。
初めて質問させていただきます。

http://www.immersivelimit.com/tutorials/create-coco-annotations-from-scratch/#coco-dataset-format

上記のサイトを参考にしながらアノテーションファイルを作ろうとしています。
以下上記サイトのコードの画像を変えただけのもの

```
from PIL import Image # (pip install Pillow)
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon

def create_sub_masks(mask_image):
    width, height = mask_image.size

    # Initialize a dictionary of sub-masks indexed by RGB colors
    sub_masks = {}
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            # Get the RGB values of the pixel
            pixel = mask_image.getpixel((x,y))[:3]

            if pixel != (0, 0, 0):
                pixel_str = str(pixel)
                sub_mask = sub_masks.get(pixel_str)
                if sub_mask is None:
                    sub_masks[pixel_str] = Image.new('1', (width+2, height+2))
                sub_masks[pixel_str].putpixel((x+1, y+1), 1)

    return sub_masks

def create_sub_mask_annotation(sub_mask, image_id, category_id, annotation_id, is_crowd):
contours = measure.find_contours(sub_mask, 0.5, positive_orientation='low')

    segmentations = []
    polygons = []
    for contour in contours:
        for i in range(len(contour)):
            row, col = contour[i]
        contour[i] = (col - 1, row - 1)

        poly = Polygon(contour)
        poly = poly.simplify(1.0, preserve_topology=False)
        polygons.append(poly)
        segmentation = np.array(poly.exterior.coords).ravel().tolist()
        segmentations.append(segmentation)

    multi_poly = MultiPolygon(polygons)
    x, y, max_x, max_y = multi_poly.bounds
    width = max_x - x
    height = max_y - y
    bbox = (x, y, width, height)
    area = multi_poly.area

    annotation = {
        'segmentation': segmentations,
        'iscrowd': is_crowd,
        'image_id': image_id,
        'category_id': category_id,
        'id': annotation_id,
        'bbox': bbox,
        'area': area
    }

    return annotation

class1_image = PIL.Image.open('./mask/class1/mask_10.jpg')
class2_image = PIL.Image.open('./mask/class2/mask_398.jpg')
class3_image = PIL.Image.open('./mask/class3/mask_0.jpg')


mask_images = [class1_image, class2_image, class3_image]

category_ids = {1: {'(255, 0, 0)': class1_id,},
                2: {'(0, 255, 0)': class2_id,},
                3: {'(0, 0, 255)': class3_id,}}

is_crowd = 0

annotation_id = 1
image_id = 1

annotations = []
for mask_image in mask_images:
    sub_masks = create_sub_masks(mask_image)
    #print(sub_masks.keys())
    for color, sub_mask in sub_masks.items():
        #print(image_id, color)
        category_id = category_ids[image_id][color]
        annotation = create_sub_mask_annotation(sub_mask, image_id, category_id, annotation_id, is_crowd)
        annotations.append(annotation)
        annotation_id += 1
    image_id += 1
```

これを実行したところ、

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     28     for color, sub_mask in sub_masks.items():
     29         #print(image_id, color)
---> 30         category_id = category_ids[image_id][color]
     31         annotation = create_sub_mask_annotation(sub_mask, image_id, category_id, annotation_id, is_crowd)
     32         annotations.append(annotation)

KeyError: '(0, 1, 5)'

この様なエラーが返ってきました。
画像は以下の物です。

mask_10.jpg
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
mask_398.jpg
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
mask_0.jpg
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

create_sub_masksがどのように動いているかよく分からず、特にここの意味がよく分からないです。

```
if sub_mask is None:
    sub_masks[pixel_str] = Image.new('1', (width+2, height+2))
    sub_masks[pixel_str].putpixel((x+1, y+1), 1)
```

勉強不足なので少しでも知恵をお借りしたいです。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

jpgでなくpngにしたら動きました。